# moogoose first record from sub-document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to use `and` condition to select the first matched record from sub-document.

`MongoDB`:

```
db.users.findOne({'$and': [{username:'kevfixx'}, {'check.month':'Jan'}, {check.year': 2015}]}, {check.$': 1})
```

In `Mongoosejs` how do I put in this {check.$': 1}:

```
User.findOne({'$and': [{username:'kevfixx'}, {'check.month': 'Jan'}, {'check.year': 2015}]}, function(err, user){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field selection is passed as a second parameter to `findOne` using a string of `'check.$'`, but you should also fix your query.

As it is now, this could match `month` against one element, and `year` against another. Use [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to require that both field match the *same* element.

And you don't need to use `$and` here as all query terms are implicitly AND'ed together.

Putting it all together, your Mongoose query should look like:

```js
User.findOne(
    {username: 'kevfixx', check: {$elemMatch: {month: 'Jan', year: 2015}}},
    'check.$',
    function (err, user) {...}
);
```